# Оптимизация редиректов, вызванных pixel code

Tags: веб-программирование, оптимизация, оптимизация-сайтов

Добрый день. Есть сайт, и в нем *pixel code* социальных сетей (Facebook, Linkedin).

При оптимизации сайта, когда я его прогоняю через *gtmetrix*, этот инструмент показывает много перенаправлений из-за этих «пикселей».

Как надо их поставить, чтобы уменьшить количество перенаправлений?

Везде и в `fb` и в `linkedin` говорят что эти скрипты надо поставить в тег `head`.
Если их поставить в футере то они будут работать нормально? Кто то знает однозначный ответ на этот вопрос?

Вот примеры перенаправлений:

> https://dc.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?time=1507530327025&pid=50231&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifcmarkets.com%2F&pageUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifcmarkets.com%2F&ref=&fmt=js&s=1
>
> https://www.bizographics.com/collect/?pid=50231&ref=&s=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifcmarkets.com%2F&pageUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifcmarkets.com%2F&fmt=js&time=1507530327025
>
> https://us-west-2.dc.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=50231&ref=&s=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifcmarkets.com%2F&pageUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifcmarkets.com%2F&fmt=js&time=1507530327025&ck=

А вот общая картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забей на редиректы

Comment: @Alex78191 Не понял вас?

Comment: Боюсь, это неизбежное/неоптимизируемое зло, но, строго говоря, за 100% соответствием и не надо стремиться, поисковики прекрасно понимают, что контроль у пользователя есть не над всем контентом, и что существует закон парето. Если вы прогоните через гугловский page insights сайт с гугловскими же картами, он посоветует заоптимизировать раздачу JS, хотя казалось бы.

Comment: @etki мне это не нужно и на 100%, просто нужно по возможности, все что можно, и для того что бы сайт грузился быстрее

Comment: Я понимаю, я просто говорю, что некоторые вещи скорее всего придется оставить как есть. Если эти события вызывают блокировку рендеринга страницы, то стоит их подключить через async js, в противном случае больших проблем с этим на самом деле нет - просто браузер сделает еще пару запросов в бэкграунде. Альтернативно можно попробовать сделать все через JS - обычно такие платформы представляют JS API - но, скорее всего, всё закончится примерно теми же редиректами.

Comment: @etki Спасибо, буду пробивать.